# Can you search for a selector that is not on the page but in a variable? - Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am wondering can this be done

```
var b = '<span id="test">hi </span> <p>some text </p>';
```

So now I want to get the hi from this variable can I somehow do a selector on b?

If it was on the page I could do `$('#test').html();`

Can this be done but passing jquery the contents of b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just pass it in and drop your selector into [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter):

```
var b = '<span id="test">hi </span> <p>some text </p>';
var testText = $(b).filter('#test').text();
```

If element you're looking for is contained within some root element in your string of HTML, use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find) instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var b = '<span id="test">hi </span> <p>some text </p>',
    $b = $('<div>').html(b);

console.log( $b.find('#test').html() ); // => hi
```

[**Example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/eGs2g/)

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
var b = $('<span id="test">hi </span> <p>some text </p>');

alert($(b).html());
```

And so does this

```
var c = $('<span id="test">hi </span> <p>some text </p>').html();

alert(c);
```